# JRequest::getVar is keeping previous values even after refreshing

Tags: joomla3.0

I am writing a mail function as a module in joomla 3. e mail works fine, but when i reload the page and insert a different email and send, but it seemed to return the previous email by  JRequest::getVar function. Is there a way to solve this issue? thanks in advance..

this is the code i used:

```
    <?php

    defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'helper.php');

    //declaration
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

    $form_send = $input->get('form_send', 'notsend');
    $fanme = $input->get('firstName');
    $lname = $input->get('lastinput');
    $email = $input->get('email', 0 , 'STRING');

    $mail=false;
    $emailexist=false;

    echo '<script>
        var php_var = "chk is first:'.$email.'";
        alert(php_var);
        </script>';
    switch ($form_send) {

        case 'send':

           if ((is_null($fanme) || is_null($lname) || is_null($email)) || (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
                echo '<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fields are empty or not valid.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br></div>';
            } else {

                    $mail = ModLittleContactHelper::SendMail($email, $fanme, $lname);
                    echo '<script>
                    var php_var = "chk when mail sending:'.$email.'";
                    alert(php_var);
                    </script>';
                   $input = JFactory::getApplication();//i have tried $app also
                   $input ->setUserState('mod_mycontact.email', null);

                }
                //echo $respond
                if (!$mail) {
                    echo 'Error sending email:';
                    require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_myecontact', 'default_tmpl'));
                }else{

                    require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_mycontact', 'sendok_tmpl'));
                    break;
                }


        default:

            require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_littlecontact', 'default_tmpl'));
            unset($var);
    }
    ?>
```

@Mario this is the helper code:

```
    class ModLittleContactHelper{
        public function SendMail($email, $fname, $lname) {


        $body = "<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:20px;'>Hi  " . $fname . " " . $lname . ",</p>";
        $body.="<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:20px;'>Welcome to Crowd Logistics! Please verify your email address below.</p><br/><br/>";
        $body.= "<hr><br/>";
        $body.= "<p style='align:center;background-color:#40B3DF;font-family:arial;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:20px;'><a href='http://suriyaarachchi.com/crowdlogistics/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=192' target='_blank'>Verify " . $email . "</a></p>";
        $body.= "<br/><hr><br/>";
        $body.="<p style='text-align:right;font-family:arial;font-size:20px;'>Or, paste this link into your browser:<br/>";
        $body.= "http://crowdlogistics/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=192<br/><br/>";
        $body.= "Thanks.<br/>";
        $body.= "CrowdLogistics</p><br/>";


        $mailer = & JFactory::getMailer();
                $mailer->setSender('info@crowdlogistics.com');
                $mailer->addRecipient($email);
                $mailer->setSubject('Mail from CrowdLogistics - Confirm your email');
                $mailer->setBody($body);
                $mailer->IsHTML(true);
                $send = & $mailer->Send();



        return $send;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to run your code on Joomla 3, there are a few things that are wrong. Below os your code, corrected where I was able to correct it. Now you have to test it in your module environment with the class being instantiated (in other words, test the below code in your module).

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'helper.php');

//declaration
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;

$form_send = $input->get('form_send', 'notsend');
$fanme = $input->get('firstName');
$lname = $input->get('lastinput');
$email = $input->get('email', 0 , 'STRING');

$mail=false;
$emailexist=false;

$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
var php_var = "chk is first:'.$email.'";
alert(php_var);
');

switch ($form_send) {

case 'send':

    if ((is_null($fanme) || is_null($lname) || is_null($email)) || (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
        echo '<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fields are empty or not valid.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br></div>';
    } else {

        $mail = ModLittleContactHelper::SendMail($email, $fanme, $lname);
        $doc->addScriptDeclaration('
                var php_var = "chk when mail sending:'.$email.'";
                alert(php_var);');
        $app->setUserState('mod_littlecontact.email', null);

    }
    //echo $respond
    if (!$mail) {
        echo 'Error sending email:';
        require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_littlecontact', 'default_tmpl'));
        break;
    }else{
        require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_littlecontact', 'sendok_tmpl'));
        break;
    }

default:

    require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_littlecontact', 'default_tmpl'));
    unset($var);
}
?>
```

Comment: @miro thank you sooo much.. but still after i submitting the form, and again reload and re submit with different email will not change alerts to new email address and email is not being deliverd to the receiver. I think there is very small error. please be good enough to solve it also. thank you sooo much... again and again..

Comment: @AnasFahumy although I would be happy to help you, any code have dependencies that are beyond the code you've posted here, which makes me unable to check what's wrong, with your entire module, instead of with your code here. Any errors might come from other code in your module.

Comment: Very sorry @Mario. I badly need to get this module to work. please help me. very sory if i am troubling you. thank you very much

Comment: I found the issue.. Mario you are correct. Error was on my joomla installation or with the template brisk. :) thanx @Mario

Answer (score 0):

First, `JRequest` class is deprecated in J3. You should use `JInput`:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$your_var = $input->get('your_var');
```

Then, regarding the email, you probably need to unset the session variables when the success is achieved (mail sent), or in other words, when you don't need them any longer.

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
// your_var is the variable you want to unset
$app->setUserState('mod_your_module.your_var', null);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me. but can you please explain what is the different between $input and $app ? i have used it as you explained. but it didnt work. can you please explain more on this?

Comment: $input and $app and just variables that become assigned. If you use $app inside your method and want to also use input, you can just declare $app = JFactory::getApplication(); and then use $app->input. Example: $my_input = $app->input; $my_input->get("my_var");

Comment: No its not working. please consider my code and suggest me an answer. Thanks alot for your concern.

Comment: Very sorry @Mario. I badly need to get this module to work. please help me. very sory if i am troubling you. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

$email = $input->get('email', 0 , 'STRING','');

4th argument for the default value,